# How to Force Nvidia Geforce Experience to recognize Warframe?

Tags: warframe, windows-10, nvidia-geforce-experience

I specified an additional folder path

```
C:\Users\win\AppData\Local\Warframe\Downloaded\Test\Tools
```

to the Nvidia Geforce Experience(NGE) program to scan the Warframe.exe to optimize its graphics. However, my NGE does not recognize the .exe when I tell it to scan for new games. What other settings in NGE must I change to get the .exe to be recognized for optimization? I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Is that even a game that can BE recognized by Geforce ? If it's not in their 'list of games' then it's just gonna ignore it. Geforce don't optimize every games.